# How to display images from the gallery of the current product in the preview of its card?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Maybe somebody know, how to display images from the gallery of the current product (.product) on the catalog page (.products) as a preview of all images?
At the moment, on the catalog page, i can to display images only for the first product.

I would be grateful for any information.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'add_custom_flipper_img', 30);

function add_custom_flipper_img() {
    
    $product->get_id();

    $id = $product->get_id();
    
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($id, 'thumbnail');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this modified code, I first used `$product->get_gallery_image_ids()` to get an array of all the image IDs in the gallery of the current product. We then check if there are any images in the gallery using if **$attachment_ids**.

#### Try below snippet once

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'add_custom_flipper_img', 30);

function add_custom_flipper_img() {
    global $product;

    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_image_ids(); // get gallery image IDs

    if ( $attachment_ids ) {
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
            echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'thumbnail' ); // display each image as thumbnail
        }
    }
}
```